# Is there a way to check if an arbitrary table item exists?

Tags: lua

I'm often deserializing JSONs into Lua tables which leads to tables with lots of nesting levels. When trying to access a non-existing one, Lua will throw the error "attempt to index a nil value". Is there a way to "catch" this error beforehand in order to check if specific table items exist, e.g.

```
local hello = {}
local v = hello.this.is.a.test
```

Is there a simple way to check if the item `hello.this.is.a.test` exists without manually checking each sub-table in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually write myself a nifty little helper function for this called `nilget` (others may call this "delve"):

```lua
local function nilget(value, ...)
    for i = 1, select("#", ...) do
        if value == nil then return nil end
        value = value[select(i, ...)]
    end
    return value
end
```

In your example, you could use this as `nilget(hello, "this", "is", "a", "test")`.

---

If you want something more similar to the `?.` operator many languages have for this, the closest construct you can get in Lua is `(t or {}).k` (which unfortunately, at least in PUC, seems to come at the runtime cost of allocating an empty table if `t` is falsey, so don't do this in performance-critical code). Your chain would be pretty verbose if written this way, though: `(((((hello or {}).this or {}).is or {}).a or {}).test`.

---

There's also the option of modifying the metatable of `nil` using `debug.setmetatable` to just return `nil` on indexing. I am just including this for fun (and the sake of completeness); you should not do this in serious code:

```lua
debug.setmetatable(nil, {__index = function() end})
```

After this, `(nil).k` will always be `nil` in your entire program (VM state), so your chain `hello.this.is.a.test` will evaluate without an error even if some items evaluate to `nil`.

Comment: `come at the runtime cost of allocating an empty table if t is falsey` - You can use pre-allocated single table instead of all `{}`

Comment: `debug.setmetatable(nil, {__index = {}})` also works

Comment: @ESkri that's right (and I do this sometimes), but that makes it even more verbose (if you count the cost of having to pass this variable around / manage it) and you may incur upvalue costs etc...

Comment: Upvalues in Lua are very cheap.  An upvalue costs almost as a local variable.

Comment: @ESkri well, local values use registers, upvalues incur an allocation and occupy an upvalue slot in a closure using them. But it is indeed much more efficient than creating fresh empty tables. The main point "against" it is the verbosity. (Of course you could use something like a one-letter name for the variable, but that would result in unreadable code.) Frankly I just wish Lua(JIT) was smart enough to optimize `(t or {}).k` it out...